# Template is not loading on Admin Dashboard in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, adminhtml, ce-1.9.2.4

Hi All I am trying to develop a section on Magento Admin Dashboard Just Like Life time sales and Average orders. Example

[image]

I have overridden Dashboard.php block to add my custom block as its child in **__prepareLayout()** function 
Here is my dashboard.php code :

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild('lastOrders',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_orders_grid')
    );

    $this->setChild('totals',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_totals')
    );

    $this->setChild('sales',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_sales')
    );

    /* Here is my custom child block */

    $this->setChild('totalOrders',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('dashboard/adminhtml_totalorders')
    );

   /* custom code end here */

    $this->setChild('lastSearches',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_searches_last')
    );

    $this->setChild('topSearches',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_searches_top')
    );

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ENABLE_CHARTS)) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_diagrams');
    } else {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')
            ->setTemplate('dashboard/graph/disabled.phtml')
            ->setConfigUrl($this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'admin')));
    }
    $this->setChild('diagrams', $block);

    $this->setChild('grids',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_grids')
    );

    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Here is my child block code :

```
class Custom_Dashboard_Block_Adminhtml_Totalorders extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('custom/dashboard/totalorders.phtml');
    }
}
```

I tried putting exit() or die() in my it and it worked child block is calling but i don't know why phtml is not loading.

My phtml path is **design/adminhtml/default/default/template/custom/dashboard/totalorders.phtml**

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Dashboard>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Dashboard>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <dashboard>Custom_Dashboard_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard</dashboard>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <dashboard>
            <class>Custom_Dashboard_Block</class>
        </dashboard>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Any help Will be appreciable.

Comment: add you custom module config.xml code.

Comment: Hello please check my question I updated it

Answer (score 1):

function _prepareLayout() generate layout for dashboard

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild('totals',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_totals'));

    }
}
```

For display your template into dashboard you have to create block and set block as a child in _prepareLayou.

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('dashboard/totalbar.phtml');
    }
}
```

you can set the template in _construct method of block

```
<div style="margin:20px;">
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals') ?>
</div>
```

all methods are set now call getChildHtml() in a dashboard to display your template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->setChild('totalOrders',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_totalorders')
    );
```

Comment: but the path of my block is local/custom/dashboard/block/adminhtml/totalorders

Comment: and block is calling problem is with phtml file